# No implementation found for boolean com.app_ad_secret.utils.PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

My game is crashing on a real device as well as on emulator & when I check in Logcat I see this error:-

> 2019-01-20 10:46:50.444 4990-4990/com.app.app_name E/art: No
>   implementation found for boolean
>   com.app_ad_secret.utils.PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive(java.lang.String)
>   (tried Java_com_app_1ad_1secret_utils_PTJniHelper_isAdNetworkActive
>   and
>   Java_com_app_1ad_1secret_utils_PTJniHelper_isAdNetworkActive__Ljava_lang_String_2) 2019-01-20 10:46:50.445 4990-4990/com.app.app_name E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.app.app_name, PID: 4990
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean
>   com.app_ad_secret.utils.PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive(java.lang.String)
>   (tried Java_com_app_1ad_1secret_utils_PTJniHelper_isAdNetworkActive
>   and
>   Java_com_app_1ad_1secret_utils_PTJniHelper_isAdNetworkActive__Ljava_lang_String_2)
>           at com.app_ad_secret.utils.PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive(Native Method)
>           at com.app.app_name.PTPlayer.onStart(**PTPlayer.java:115**)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

**When I opened that `(PTPlayer.java:115)`, it took me to this method:-**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAdMob")) {
        rohit_ad_chart_boost.onStart( this );
    }
}
```

I don't understand the problem here & what's causing this?

Comment: Can't anyone even tell me what causing this error. I am not asking for solution just tell me what is this error?

Comment: Thanks guys & all those android experts, thanks for helping me out. I owe everyone here big time. It was my mistake to share my problem here.